# In Django how to user Application A serializer in Application B and manipulate a value using SerializerMethodField

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

App a --> serializer.py
App b --> serializer.py

Now in a App I need to import b serializer.py
In app a 
from b.serializers import aserializers
class aserializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):

Now I've a filed "is_prod" in a serializers whose value is either 1 or 0 if it is 1 it should prod and if it's 0 it should show non-prod.

I can't use App b serializers as it's already written and used in various places.

Comment: Are the models used in different apps have the connection?

Comment: Yes, they have connection. Based on a column account_id ...App A model(account_id), App B model(account_id)

Comment: Could you improve your question a bit by uploading your codes, or some similar example source code so that I could help you. Be a little more specific.